# Extract a particular text from variable in shell script

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk

I have 2 variables

```
VAL1="C70AN"
VAL2="MBA30"
```

and I have one Directory in my system `/opt/web/C70/MBA/`

How can I go to this directory using variables

for example `cd  /opt/web/$VAL1/$VAL2`

How can I extract the particular text from variable in shell script?

Comment: [Shell Command Language - Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02)

Comment: If you need the first 3 characters for both (always), then ${val1:0:3}. same for val2

Comment: Do you always need the first 3 characters of the variable value? Could be more or less? Under what conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Anthon is perfectly correct, though it implies a bit too much typing IMO. I suggest defining a shell (bash) function named (eg.) "mycd" as a wrapper:

```
function mycd {
  cd /opt/web/${VAL1:0:3}/${VAL2:0:3}
}
```

Now, no matter whatever values the variables $VAR1 and $VAR1 currently have, calling this function will change directory to the expected location.

Try the following example in a running bash terminal, hitting ENTER at the end of each input line window):

```
user% cd; pwd
/home/user
user% function mycd { cd /opt/web/${VAL1:0:3}/${VAL2:0:3} }
user% export VAL1="C70AN"; export VAL2="MBA30"
user% mycd
user% pwd
/opt/web/C70/MBA
user%
```

This example of course requires the existence of the directory tree "/opt/web/C70/MBA" to work. If this ist not the case, you will receive an error message like

```
bash: cd: /opt/web/C70/MBA: file or directory not found
```

This result is still a prove for the correct work of the "mycd" function as it tries to change to the calculated directory - which does not (yet) exist.

HTH,
too

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash)[shell](/questions/tagged/shell)[function](/questions/tagged/function)[variable](/questions/tagged/variable)[substring](/questions/tagged/substring)